# Is Entity Framework provider for Firebird reliable enought?

Tags: entity-framework, firebird

Has anybody tried to use EF provider (.NET 3.5 SP1) for Firebird (embedded server in my case) in production?
Can it be considered stable enough for commercial development?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about the Entity Framework but I do use the Firebird .net Data Provider on production and it's rock solid.

Answer (score 0):

It's work fine. I hadn't got bugs in work with this firebird and entity framework. I develope huge application now and use that products very active. I didn't see bugs in firebird .NET provider, but i saw little bug in entity framework. I have only one problem - to install firebird for using in Entity Framework and make settings. It can take about one working day. So after it you can use this product quietly.